# Replace Xamarin forms page without pushasync

Tags: xamarin, authentication

I've searched through numerous online posts and can't find a suitable answer for this scenario. It's a pretty common requirement. I have a Xamarin.Forms app with a login page and listing page.  When the app is started, the login page is displayed.  When they login successfully, I want to display the listing page and prevent them from backing up by clicking on the toolbar back button or the hardware back button.

Answer (score 2):

Change the MainPage

when you start the app you should have

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
```

after login, something like

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new MyFirstPageAfterLogin();
```

Comment: Thanks!  That 's just what I needed.